# Что за ошибка? Expected an identifier, but got 'var'

Tags: dart

Начал изучать Dart и столкнулся с очень странной ошибкой:

```
foo() {
  var items = [1, 2, 3];
  
  return items.map((n) => {
    var m = n * 2;
    return m;
  });
}

Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'var'.
Try inserting an identifier before 'var'.
    var m = n * 2;
    ^^^
```

Я реально не понимаю что тут нет так...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справа от `=>` должно [стоять выражение](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#:%7E:text=as%20arrow%20syntax.-,Note,-%3A%20Only%20an%20expression), т.е. expression.

В вашем случае должно быть либо `(n) => n*2` либо `(n) { var m = n*2; return m; }`

Comment: Аа, для многострочных лямбд стрелочка не нужна? Теперь понятно.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК первое время такие мелкие расхождения с Javascript взрывают мозг и рука тянется за пистолетом, чтобы пристрелить всех тех затейников, которые сделали очередной JS )

Comment: Но язык прикольный)) И UI удобно делать без html на Flutter. Просто ошибка, зараза, не информативная.